# how use frequently an AS code without increase CPU usage?

Tags: flash, actionscript, cpu-usage

i have created an animation (kind of tween) in flash by AS,

i want to use it more than once in my project, but CPU usage increase very much!

i think save my animate as swf and load it in my project.

is good idea?

how do it?

can you suggest me efficient way?

thanks...

Comment: You will need to show us some code and give us more information. How complex is the tween, how often are you calling it, how many objects, etc etc

Comment: @user663431 no, not as a rar file. If you want to show code, copy&paste it into your question, then use the code formatting tools (the curly braces) to mark and format it. Maybe you should read one or two other questions to get an idea how it's done.

Answer (score 1):

If your animation is 400 bricks and multiple rows, and I assume made in Flash as a vector MovieClip (i.e. not an image), then your CPU usage is coming from Flash having to draw a ton of vectors every frame. This becomes especially true when you start using multiple instances of it.

Take a look at `cacheAsBitmap` (http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/DisplayObject.html#cacheAsBitmap) if you're only moving your image around (not scaling or rotating it), or do as www0z0k suggested and draw it out as BitmapData objects.

You can also check out SWFSheet from bit101 - http://www.bit-101.com/blog/?s=swfsheet - it basically does the hard work for you by drawing out your animation as a series of PNG images that you can then load in

Answer (score 0):

some code'd be useful.
but if you need to repeat exactly the same animation many times (and it's created at runtime) you can call `BitmapData.draw()` for each frame of animation when it's played for the first time and store that BitmapDatas in an `Array` or `Vector` to show them every next time instead of original animation

Comment: its possible but is equal to i should rewrite my code,And i think is still high cpu consumption, because run animations have interferes (!).

Comment: @user663431 - can you post code parts that seem to be most cpu hungry? it should be possible to optimize it